# KVM Guest VM (ubuntu) cannot access internet

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, linux-kvm, hypervisor

This might be common issue and I have tried many things and still no luck and looking help here. I have look similar issue here but none resolve, please advise. My kvm vm guest cannot access internet. Only able to ping host-guest. I have setup virtualbox vm centos as a host and installed kvm hypervisor. I create br0 via host enp0s3 interface (dhcp) and my centos vm can ping router gateway, my physical pc and can access internet. Ok... virtualbox host VM centos working no problem.

Than I install kvm (refer to web) and also virtual manager. I have default network created (virbr0), 192.168.122.0/24. libvrt running. I than create new guest ubuntu vm in host vm centos and network using br0 (dhcp) ubuntu vm created and able to get dhcp ip (same subnet as vm centos and physical pc).

Vm ubuntu guest able to ping Vm centos and vise versa. The problem here guest vm ubuntu cannot access internet and cannot ping physical pc also or any other pc in my lan. I have tried stop host firewall, stop selinux but still d same problem. I even create another vm that connect to virbr0 (nat) and that vm not even can get dhcp ip from virbr0 (when ifconfig only show lo ip...try add manual ens3 interface still cannot get the ip)... somethg wrong with my kvm setup? Please help me...I have troubleshoot this problem for almost a week without any good progress...thank you.

```
Setup:-
(dhcp)
PC Physical(virtualbox) ---- VM Centos(KVM) -----VM Ubuntu
192.168.0.141                192.168.0.186       192.168.0.197

promiscuous mode - enable all.

Host ifconfig (VM Centos):-
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.186  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee3:4a2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:e68:5435:ccce:a00:27ff:fee3:4a2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 08:00:27:e3:4a:2a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65476  bytes 5739488 (5.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78582  bytes 31486452 (30.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee3:4a2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e3:4a:2a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65950  bytes 6904753 (6.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 99518  bytes 43841885 (41.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 120478  bytes 254106018 (242.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 120478  bytes 254106018 (242.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe8e:eff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:a7:e4:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 133  bytes 35092 (34.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 698 (698.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fea7:e402  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:a7:e4:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 103  bytes 32268 (31.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1107  bytes 57804 (56.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe08:d031  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:08:d0:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1289  bytes 66978 (65.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2083  bytes 232676 (227.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3
TYPE=Ethernet
#PROXY_METHOD=none
#BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
#DEFROUTE=yes
#IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
#IPV6INIT=yes
#IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
#IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
#IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
#IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
#UUID=2d8ceee7-bef3-4bba-b5bc-4b83df69530a
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
HWADDR=08:00:27:e3:4a:2a
NM_CONTROLLED=no

br0
#This is for using DHCP
DEVICE=br0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
#IPV6INIT=yes
#IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
STP=on
DELAY=0
NM_CONTROLLED=no


virsh netlist:-
Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active   no           yes


brctl show:-
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.080027e34a2a       yes             enp0s3
                                                        vnet1
virbr0          8000.fe5400a7e402       yes             vnet0

route host (vm centos)
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0


nmcli c show --active
NAME    UUID                                  TYPE    DEVICE
virbr0  95561712-74ce-42c9-a9d8-6a0baf6cbaeb  bridge  virbr0

iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:websm ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Guest ifconfig (vm ubuntu) (I cannot ssh as no ssh server install, i just type here to show d info)
ens3    inet addr:192.168.0.197
lo  inet addr:127.0.0.1

route:-
destination gateway     genmask     use iface
0.0.0.0     192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0     ens3
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   ens3

ens3
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```